# Build output difference - VS Build vs dotnet build

Tags: visual-studio, dotnet-build

I am trying to implement a pre-commit hook where I build the solution and check for any warnings. When I build the solution in VS I am getting warning but where as when I run dotnet build using powershell I get zero warnings.

Below is the CLI  `dotnet build --no-incremental --configuration Release` and the result I get is like "Determining projects to restore and so on and at the end I can see Build succeeded with 0 Warning(s)"
But if I do a normal build in VS I can see there are two warnings.
The warnings are part of the custom .editorconfig file I have added.

So the PS command won't consider the .editorconfig file ?

I tried dotnet clean as well which ideally cleans and builds the solution again but there also I am getting 0 warning(s).

Answer (score 0):

I added the property AllEnabledByDefault as mentioned in the link ([Link](https://makolyte.com/how-to-enable-the-built-in-net-analyzers/)) to get the Code Analysis response in the build event.